# WordPress - translations not appended even strings are edited

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, translation

Well after 5 days of trying to find solution, I think I need WordPress magician to help me solve this.

I am translating my WordPress site. So far I have translated over 80% of the content mainly accessing **.po** files via `server` or by using [LocoTranslate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

I have troubles with translating some specific content on the page:

When accessing `Products` section in WordPress Dashboard I can see that even the settings are translated (to Danish) but some content of the same product page are not.

Image Of PRODUCT page:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

- Checked all *In Stock* strings via LocoTranslate plugin (for main theme po file and plugins file) and all are translated to Danish.
- I changed Main language in General WP Settings
- Tried [TranslatePress](https://translatepress.com/) plugin, and when accessing the page via it, it does not offer an option to translate *In Stock* part. Evan tough it offers an option to translate action button and I did that.

As I can see on the editing page In Stock is clearly part:
Product settings on Dashboard
[image]

This means "In Stock" and even here is translated, too.

Note: When refreshing the page the translation is seen for a part of a second for the BUTTON, then it changes back to English.

Well, I am desperate. Can someone offer some other solution how I can fix this?

Comment: You really should ask this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com -- people there are more familiar with WordPress.

Comment: I did. Thank you. Maybe someone can help on this side, too. :) @O.Jones

Comment: Sorry, but there is not enough information to help you with what you seek, as this has to do with an addon to WooCommerce, and isn't because of WC Core.  Also, this question is probably both off-topic for this site as well as the WPSE site, since on that site plugins are off-topic, and here, you would be getting help with a coding issue.